# CDI bean configuration using beans.xml file

Tags: java, jsf-2, java-ee-6, cdi, weld

I have very simple CDI bean:

```
package net.resourceAuth;

public class Sample {

   private String text;

   public String getText() {
    return text;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
   }
}
```

And now I would like to initialize `text` variable using `beans.xml`. I'm trying with `beans.xml` file like this one:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:res="urn:java:net.resourceAuth"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <res:Sample>
      <res:text>test123</res:text>
    </res:Sample>

</beans>
```

But it does not work. `text` is always null. Can You help me figure out what is wrong here?

In other words: I am looking for a similar solution as it is used in the JSF  faces-config.xml described for example here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/configure-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in solution for this problem. You can use some third party solutions like Apache DeltaSpike http://deltaspike.apache.org/ or implement it by Your own using CDI extensions for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not aware that this kind of configuration can be made in `beans.xml` (this probably works just in Spring but maybe somebody will correct me). The CDI way of initializing the values is the method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, so try this

```
public class Sample {

    private String text;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         this.text = "aaa";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to configure this component (set starting value for `text`) in external properties file. Thus Your answer does not meet my requirements. Maybe You know another way to do such a configuration?

Comment: I know but like I said, I doubt that there is any other option which `CDI`. Anyway, where did you get the syntax of `<res:Sample>` in `beans.xml`?

Comment: That's an old reference. That will not work. There is nothing in CDI, or any implementations that will allow you to do this. You could write an extension to allow you to do it, but it's messy.

Comment: So is there any other way to  fulfill my requirement? To configure CDI beans in external files. Similar like in JSF Managed Beans ( faces-config.xml file)?

Comment: @pWoz I think Apache DeltaSpike has a `@ConfigValue` feature implemented but last I checked it wasn't documented. Try emailing the user list with your requirements, they are usually pretty quick at answering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to implement a javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension that @Observes ProcessInjectionTarget like this [Wrapping an InjectionTarget](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e5267) ?

This example inject bean values from resource bundle.

Comment: I haven't yet. I thought that there is a built-in solution for my problem. But probably I will have to implement it by my own.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample link that you posted if you see the .xml file it uses the package name and then the class name so if you try to change from `<ress:Sample>` to `<ress:net.resourceAuth.Sample>` it might work.

Answer (score 0):

EJB´s can be configured via XML ..it is the ejb-jar.xml